# Manipulate labeling/2 output PROLOG

Tags: prolog, counter, clpfd, restrictions, labeling

I'm developing a PROLOG program with restrictions to find the solutions for a certain game.

Question#1: For debugging purposes, I want to count the number of possible solutions of the game. Is there any way to do this via the `labeling/2` predicate?

My goal is to count the number of possible combinations between the cubes (*Instant Insanity*):

```
insanity2(Vars) :-
        Vars = [F1,B1,R1,L1,U1,D1,
                F2,B2,R2,L2,U2,D2,
                F3,B3,R3,L3,U3,D3,
                F4,B4,R4,L4,U4,D4],

        /* Colors range (4 colors) */
        domain(Vars, 1,4),

        /* Restrictions */
        %Color restrictions
          % Cube #1
        alocCubeColors(F1,B1,R1,L1,U1,D1),
          % Cube #2
        alocCubeColors(F2,B2,R2,L2,U2,D2),
          % Cube #3
        alocCubeColors(F3,B3,R3,L3,U3,D3),
          % Cube #4
        alocCubeColors(F4,B4,R4,L4,U4,D4),

        %Logic restrictions
        F1#\=F2, F1#\=F3, F1#\=F4, F2#\=F3, F2#\=F4, F3#\=F4,
        B1#\=B2, B1#\=B3, B1#\=B4, B2#\=B3, B2#\=B4, B3#\=B4,
        R1#\=R2, R1#\=R3, R1#\=R4, R2#\=R3, R2#\=R4, R3#\=R4,
        L1#\=L2, L1#\=L3, L1#\=L4, L2#\=L3, L2#\=L4, L3#\=L4,
        labeling([], Vars).
```

Question#2: Is it possible to manipulate `labeling/2` output, in order to rearranje it in a proper way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your question #1 you can use the `findall/3` predicate:

Ex:

```
| ?- X=[X1,X2], domain(X,0,2), findall(X, labeling([],X), Xl ), length(Xl,L).            
X = [X1,X2],
Xl = [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,0],[1,1],[1,2],[2,0],[2,1],[2,2]],
L = 9,
X1 in 0..2,
X2 in 0..2 ? 
yes
| ?-
```

Comment: Very nice (+1)! If you only want the *number* of solutions and want to preserve some memory, you can use for example : `findall(` **t** `, labeling([],Vs), Ts)`